# How to access the Cambridge dictionary website with Python?

Tags: python

Sorry, I'm a newbie. I need to access this website with Python https://dictionary.cambridge.org

This is what I try:

```
from urllib import *
url = 'https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/flower'

print (request.urlopen(url).read())
```

This is what I get:

```
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\http\client.py", line 275, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"

RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response
```

Can you share any ideas how I can access this website?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can use the API - https://dictionary.cambridge.org/develop.html

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

```
url = 'https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/flower'
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)'
headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}
req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers)
with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
   html = response.read()
print(html)
```

**Explanation**

Currently the connection is being terminated because of no headers in the request.

Comment: Your code returns an error to me: TypeError: can't concat str to bytes

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-114c07b53682> in <module>
      3 headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}
      4 req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers)
----> 5 with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
      6    html = response.read()
      7 print(html)
...

Answer (score 0):

[image]
The code below talks about the same way you can request to cambridge.
note that (user_agent) will vary depending on the version, you can go to cambridge then F12 on windows to get the corresponding user_agent, hope it helps you.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/french-english/bonjour'
user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.5005.63 Safari/537.36"
headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}
web_request = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(web_request.text, "html.parser")
//do somthing
```